# Unable to form JQ as per requirement

Tags: json, jq

I am using JQ Play.

Here is my JSON Data -

```
{
"body":{
"primarykey": [
    "book_id",
    "edition_id"
],
"members": [
    {
        "name": "book_id",
        "type": "NUMBER"
    },
    {
        "name": "edition_id",
        "type": "NUMBER"
    },
    {
        "name": "title",
        "type": "VARCHAR2"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "collection",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/metadata-catalog/",
        "mediaType": "application/json"
    },
    {
        "rel": "canonical",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/metadata-catalog/books/",
        "mediaType": "application/json"
    },
    {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/open-api-catalog/books/",
        "mediaType": "application/openapi+json"
    },
    {
        "rel": "describes",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/books/"
    }
]
}
}
```

My JQ -

```
.body.primarykey[] | "{" + . + "}"
```

Current Output -

```
"{book_id}"
"{edition_id}"
```

My expected output is -

```
{"book_id"},{"edition_id"}
```

Here if there are more primary keys, they should also get appended in expected output.

Please help me with correct JQ that will work in jqplay.org

Comment: What type of output are you trying to generate? The provided example is not valid JSON. Are you trying to generate raw strings? Is it important to skip the final comma?

Comment: hello @knittl, please refer my expected output. I dont want slash "\" in output and also I just want comma to separate those multiple fileds present under primarykey

Comment: Please refer to my answer, from what I understood it produces the output exactly as specified. If it doesn't, please clarify

Comment: your JQ produces following output -
 "{\"book_id\"},"
"{\"edition_id\"}," 

but my expected output is - 
{"book_id"},
{"edition_id"}

here there are no slashes in expected output and also there is one comma to separate fields.

Comment: hi @knittl, I have updated expected output in question so please check and provide jq accordingly.

Comment: Did you run the command from my answer? It doesn't print any backslashes. After editing, your expected output changed completely (previously it was multiple lines, with the words quoted, now it is a single line which is quoted as a whole). Please don't change your question when there are already answers and those become invalidated

Comment: this is your jq output - "{book_id},{edition_id}" and I am expecting - {"book_id"},{"edition_id"} you can see we need double quotes for "book_id" and "edition_id" like this. we dont want double quotes outside of both records

Comment: Your last comment doesn't match your question at all! The question states: »My expected output is `"{book_id},{edition_id}"`«. You really have to decide what output you want and not change it by the hour. Nevertheless, my answer provides jq commands to produce either output

Comment: yeah, I got the issue. I missed to update the expected output in my question. Now you can see thats updated. So need JQ that will give following output - {"book_id"},{"edition_id"}

Comment: I would have expected you to be able to change `join(",\n")` to `join(",")` if you want to get rid of the newlines. Nevertheless, my answer now includes the necessary commands to generate all 3 versions that were asked in different revisions of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce the output as requested in the initial version of this question, i.e. multiple lines, each key quoted and enclosed in curly braces:

```
{"book_id"},
{"edition_id"}
```

you can run the following jq command (with raw output):

```
jq -r '.body.primarykey | map("{\"\(.)\"}") | join(",\n")'
```

---

To produce the new output after the question was edited, i.e. a single quoted line, each key enclosed in curly braces:

```
"{book_id},{edition_id}"
```

you can run:

```
jq '.body.primarykey | map("{\(.)}") | join(",")'
```

---

To produce the output of the third installment of the question, use the same command as for the first version, but join only with `,` and without a line break:

```
jq -r '.body.primarykey | map("{\"\(.)\"}") | join(",")'
```

This will output a single line, each key quoted and enclosed in curly braces; and multiple keys separated by a comma:

```
{"book_id"},{"edition_id"}
```

---

Please note that neither output is valid JSON, and as such cannot be further processed with jq.

Comment: your third jq giving slashes in output - "{\"book_id\"},{\"edition_id\"}" is it obvious ? can we remove that back slashes ?

Comment: @sujay777 it doesn't. Did you run the command from my answer?

Comment: yes @knittl , you can see this - https://jqplay.org/s/s2ZXORv5XBP

Comment: @sujay777 that's a completely different jq program. If I replace it with the exact program from my question, I get the output `{"db_number"}`

Comment: updated the link, please see now - https://jqplay.org/s/s2ZXORv5XBP

Comment: @sujay777 you didn't check "raw output" (the `-r` option). The command(s) as presented in my answer produce exactly the output(s) as requested in the question

Comment: yes @knittl, but we cannot use -r in jqplay. I want JQ that will work in jqplay.org

Comment: @sujay777 um, yes, you can? Just tick the "raw output" checkbox (»you didn't check "raw output"«). jqplay simply calls jq on a server. https://jqplay.org/s/dAky1eBTgPi

Comment: Got it. Thanks @knittl. I am getting expected output now.